# Display the list of items on webpage, that have not been updated in the last 3 days

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php

   if (!$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password')) {
   die('An error occurred while connecting to the MySQL server!<br><br>' . 
   mysql_error());
 }

 if (!mysql_select_db('mydb')) { die('An error occurred while connecting 
 to the database!<br><br>' . mysql_error()); }

// Create an array of MySQL queries to run
  $sql = array( 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS appengage.updateon;', 'CREATE TABLE 
   appengage.updateon SELECT start_date, updated_on FROM mydb.issues 
   WHERE start_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 Day) AND NOW();'
  );

// Run the MySQL queries
if (sizeof($sql) > 0) {
foreach ($sql as $query) {
    if (!mysql_query($query)) {
        die('A MySQL error has occurred!<br><br>' . mysql_error());
    }
}
}
?>
```

Above code giving the records which were updated in last days but i want which are not updated in last 3 days.

Comment: Stop. Avail yourself of any beginners book or tutorial published in the last 3 years, and start over.

Answer (score 0):

Change you code by this way:

```
// Create an array of MySQL queries to run
  $sql = array( 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS appengage.updateon;', 'CREATE TABLE 
   appengage.updateon SELECT start_date, updated_on FROM mydb.issues 
   WHERE start_date NOT BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 Day) AND NOW();'
  );
```

I added `NOT` before `BETWEEN DATE_SUB`

Comment: this code giving all the records but i want only last 3 days records which are not updated.

Comment: do you have update_date or something like it in mydb.issues table?

Comment: $sql = array( 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS appengage.updateon;', 'CREATE TABLE 
   appengage.updateon SELECT start_date, updated_on FROM mydb.issues 
   WHERE start_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 Day) AND NOW() AND UPDATE_ON IS NULL;'
  );

Comment: or 'UPDATE_ON = start_date' depends of your INSERT logic

Comment: Is there any other option for getting not updated records.